# How to process a 64 GB CSV file in Pyspark efficiently?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I have a very large CSV file in a blob storage nearly of size 64 GB. I need to do some processing on top of every row and push the data to DB.
What should be the best solution to do this efficiently?

Comment: Processing is reading + writing? consider an equivalent table in the DB design, else efficiently is gone.

Comment: large files are never recommended as processing speed deteriorates.

Comment: @SamGinrich by processing I mean:
1. Reading data 
2.creating a dataframe using data from CSV
3. Writing dataframe to DB.

Comment: So, it's actually about importing as CSV stream into a DB scheme!? You'll read the CSV line by line. Of Python libraries, supporting this, I have no idea.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show what you've done so far, along with specific issues/errors you're running into (share your pyspark/notebook code). There's really no way to know the *best* way for you to process your data, as you haven't shared any details (schema, transforms being done, etc). Lots of ways to go about this. And the term "efficiently" is really broad and open-ended.

Comment: @SamGinrich - not quite sure what you're getting at, but pyspark, and spark in general, is built for such content ingest/transform, and is a common use-case. And nothing in this question hints at spark streaming (as written). The issue here is just around lack of detail in the original question.

Comment: @samkart - 64GB isn't really a large file, when it comes to distributed processing in Spark; telling someone a large file is "never" recommended... really doesn't make too much sense in the real world. And we don't often have the luxury of specifying input file sizes.

Comment: @DavidMakogon people with the luxury of adding unlimited resources should not really wrap their heads here. A static 64GB single file is indeed a large file.

Answer (score 1):

64 GB file size shouldn't be the reason to worry you as Pyspark is even capable to process even 1TB of data.

You can use Azure Databricks to write the code in Pyspark and run it on cluster.

> A Databricks cluster is a set of computation resources and
> configurations on which you run data engineering, data science, and
> data analytics workloads, such as production ETL pipelines, streaming
> analytics, ad-hoc analytics, and machine learning.

You can refer this third-party tutorial [Read a CSV file stored in blob container using python in DataBricks](https://transform365.blog/2019/12/16/read-a-csv-file-stored-in-blob-container-using-python-in-databricks/).

Though you shouldn't face any issue while processing the file but if required you can consider [Boost Query Performance with Databricks and Spark](https://key2consulting.com/boost-query-performance-databricks-spark/)
.

Comment: This really isn't an answer - it's a link to some tutorials. The question is open-ended and there's just no way to answer it (hence my comments from a few days ago). Since then, the OP has not responded - there's no additional information provided. Please don't post answers like this.

Comment: @David sure "pyspark, and spark in general, is built for such content ingest/transform, and is a common use-case"